# Number of $x \in [0,1]^n$ such that Ax integer

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, polyhedra

If $A$ is an integer matrix in $\mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$, why is there only a finite number of vectors $x \in [0,1]^n$ such that $Ax$ is a vector of integers?

Comment: $Ax$ is a vector, not an integer...

Comment: An integer vector I mean

Comment: Then this is not true... Every matrix will satisfy this.

Comment: No, by [0,1] I mean the interval. If A is a 2x2 matrix of all ones and x = [1/3, 1/3], then Ax is not a vector of integers.

Comment: This is not true in general: If $A$ is the zero matrix, $Ax$ is an integer vector for every vector $x$. There has to be some extra condition.

Comment: I thought about it some more and it is even less true than I thought: Take $A$ to be the row vector $(1, 1)$. Then $Ax$ is simply the sum of the components of $x$ and for any $x_1 \in [0,1]$ you can choose $x_2 = 1 - x_1$ to get an integer.

Comment: Luna, in the light of daw's answer, you should try to convince yourself that this thing is true if _and only if_ $A$ is invertible. (In particular, for $A$ to be invertible, we require $m=n$.)

Comment: @TonyK I edited my answer: the claim is true if and only if $\ker A=\{0\}$.

Comment: @daw: Oh yes, you are right. (But shouldn't your $m>n$ be $m\ge n$?)

Comment: @TonyK, yes of course

Answer (score 3):

> The claim is true if and only if $\ker A=\{0\}$.

Let $\ker A=\{0\}$. Then necessarily $m\ge n$ and there is $B\in \mathbb R^{n,m}$ such that $BA=I_n$.

Since multiplication with $A$ is a linear and bounded map, the image $A([0,1]^n)$ of $[0,1]^n$ is bounded, so $A([0,1]^n) \cap \mathbb Z^m$ is a finite set.
Then the set of vectors $x\in [0,1]^n$ with $Ax\in \mathbb Z^m$ is precisely
$$
B \left( A([0,1]^n) \cap \mathbb Z^m \right),
$$
which is finite as well.

Let now $y \in \ker A$, $y\ne 0$. Since $A$ is an integer matrix, it holds $Ax\in \mathbb Z^m$ for all $x\in \{0,1\}^n$.

Now define $x$ as 
$$
x_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } y_i<0,\\
0 & \text{ if } y_i\ge0.
\end{cases}$$
Then for all $t\ge0$ small enough, $x+ty\in [0,1]^n$ and $A(x+ty)=Ax\in \mathbb Z^m$.